# Access ListBox: Where condition issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, macros

I'm having an issue getting a list box to work.  The list itself refers to a table that contains the names of employees (A field named [Techs]).  This table is used to populate a 'master' table that contains tasks assigned to those employees (field: [Responsible])

The aim here is to make it so an employee can be added to the table and in turn the list and all associated data will be updated with that name, but that tasks can be queried against the name itself, without a user having to design a new query every time.  I set up a query with everyone's name and their assigned tasks.  Then I made the list box.  I want it to run the query where the name matches what name the user clicks on.

This is my where condition in the macro:

```
[Techs]=[Forms]![FindbyName]![Responsible]
```

I'm getting the dialogue that shows the first clause of WHERE at the top and a search box at the bottom.

Comment: The dialogue is titled: "Enter Parameter Value"

Comment: "Techs" is the name of the parameter.   

This is the query I set up that the macro is referencing:                   

SELECT Master.Responsible, Master.[Task Name], Master.Description, Master.Location, Master.Due
FROM Master;

Comment: That query doesn't even mention *Techs*, so I don't see why Access asks for a value for it.  Is *Master* a table or the name of a query?

Comment: I think that _Techs_ might reference the macro itself, or _Techs_ may be the product of the fact that the _Techs_ Table informs the _Master_ Table who is responsible [Responsible] for a task.

Comment: Does *Master* include a lookup field?

Comment: Yes to three other tables and a user-input list

Comment: Did the *Techs* field get renamed or removed in one of those other tables after the *Master* lookup fields were created?

Comment: I would say that's very likely.  I made a bunch of changes at the beginning.

Comment: I emailed you a copy of the database.  Sorry for all the fluff.  Thanks for any help that you're willing to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Where Condition* in your embedded macro's `OpenForm` action references a field, *Techs*, which does not exist in the target form's *Record Source*.  Therefore Access does not recognize the field name in that context, and assumes it must be a parameter.

Change the `OpenForm` *Where Condition* to use a field which does exist in the *Record Source*:

```
[Responsible]=[Forms]![Find PM]![List38]
```